# How to use database object in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble passing data to my view when using `$query->row()` I can only seem to get the value when using it in the controller.

Here's the model:

```
public function get_post($post_id) {

    $this->db->select('id, date, title');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->where('id', $post_id);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $row = $query->row();

    $row->title = html_purify($row->title);
    $row->date_posted_iso = date('c', $row->date);

    return $row;
}
```

The controller:

```
public function post($post_id) {

    $row = $this->post_model->get_post($post_id);
    $this->data['post'] = $row;

    $this->data['meta_title'] = $row->title;

    $this->template->build('post/show_post', $this->data);
```

}

The view:

```
<?php 

foreach ($post as $row): 

echo $row->date;
echo $row->title;

endforeach;

?>
```

The line `$this->data['meta_title'] = $row->title;` in the controller works correctly, but I don't want to explicitly define all of those variables in the controller.

I've tried with the foreach and without and get `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

How can I correctly echo the value in my view using `$query->row()`?

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning a row, you don't need a `foreach` loop, try changing your view code to:

```
<?php  
    echo $post->date;
    echo $post->title;
?>
```

The variable should be `$post` and not `$row` as you define `post` element in the `data` array in your controller.

Comment: that's what I tried first and was surprised that didn't work, so I tried a foreach and some other combinations to try and figure it out.

Comment: `var_dump($post);` in view, see what it outputs

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this.............

```
 public function post($post_id)
 {

   $row = $this->post_model->get_post($post_id);

   $model = array();

   $model['post'] = $row;

   $this->template->build('post/show_post', $model);
}
```

In view fie do like this

```
foreach($post as $data)

  {

      echo $data['title'];
  }
```